# removing commas from numbers in CSV file

Tags: csv, sed

I have a file that has many columns and I only need two of those columns. I am getting the columns I need using

```
cut -f 2-3 -d, file1.csv > file2.csv
```

The issue I am having is that the first column is ID and once it gets past `999` it becomes `1,000` and so it is treated as an extra column now. I cant get rid of all commas because I need them to separate the data. Is there a way to use `sed` to remove commas that only show up between `0-9`?

Comment: It would be very helpful if you included a small sample of your input and your desired output in the question.

Comment: here is a sample 1,234,"email@email.com","name","lastname","phone","address" I only need email and name columns.

Comment: You should edit your question to show a few lines and your expected output.

Comment: That's unfortunate that you have a broken CsV file.

Comment: yeah we are getting lists from all kinds of people and I have to go through all the data and get just what we need and the lists are not always set up very well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for the example in the comments:

```
awk -F'"?,"' '{print $2, $3}' file
```

The field separator is zero or one `"` followed by `,"`. This means that the comma in the first number doesn't count.

To separate the two fields with a comma instead of a space, you can change the `OFS` variable like this:

```
awk -F'"?,"' -v OFS=',' '{print $2, $3}' file
```

Or like this:

```
awk -F'"?,"' 'BEGIN{OFS=","}{print $2, $3}' file
```

Alternatively, if you want the quotes as well, you can use `printf`:

```
awk -F'"?,"' '{printf "\"%s\",\"%s\"\n", $2, $3}' file
```

Comment: perfect this is just what I needed, now I just need to replace the space with a comma but thats easy. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a real CSV parser, and count backwards from the end of the line:

```
ruby -rcsv -ne '
  row = $_.parse_csv
  puts row[-5..-4].to_csv :force_quotes => true
' <<END
999,"someone@example.com","Doe, John","Doe","555-1212","address"
1,234,"email@email.com","name","lastname","phone","address"
END
```

```
"someone@example.com","Doe, John"
"email@email.com","name"
```

Comment: +1 I have very little experience of ruby one-liners but the CSV parser looks quite neat.

Answer (score 0):

From your comments, it sounds like there is a comma and a space (`', '`) pattern between tokens.

If this is the case, you can do this easily with sed.  The strategy is to first replace all occurrences of `,` with some unique character sequence (like maybe `||`).

```
's:, :||:g'
```

From there you can remove all commas:

```
's:,::g'
```

Finally, replace the double pipes with comma-space again.

```
's:||:, :g'
```

Putting it into one statement:

```
sed -i -e 's:, :||:g;s:,::g;s:||:, :g' your_odd_file.csv
```

And a command-line example to try before you buy:

```
bash$ sed -e 's:, :||:g;s:,::g;s:||:, :g' <<< "1,200,000, hello world, 123,456"
1200000, hello world, 123456
```

If you are in the unfortunate situation where there is *not* a space between fields in the CSV - you can attempt to 'fake it' by detecting changes in data type - like where there is a numeric field followed by a text field.

```
's:,\([^0-9]\):, \1:g'  # numeric followed by non-numeric
's:\([^0-9]\),:\1, :g'  # non-numeric field followed by something (anything)
```

You can put this all together into one statement, but you are venturing into dangerous waters here - this will definitely be a one-off solution and should be taken with a large grain of salt.

```
sed -e 's:,\([^0-9]\):, \1:g;s:\([^0-9]\),:\1, :g' \
    -e 's:, :||:g;s:,::g;s:||:, :g' file1.csv > file2.csv
```

And another example:

```
bash$ sed -e 's:,\([^0-9]\):, \1:g;s:\([^0-9]\),:\1, :g' \
          -e 's:, :||:g;s:,::g;s:||:, :g' <<< "1,200,000,hello world,123,456"
1200000, hello world, 123456
```

Comment: there are no spaces between them unfortunately